# Minimum components needed to automate Word 2013 VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-word, office-automation, word-automation

I created a Microsoft Word 2013 Automation process that opens a Microsoft Word template, replaces bookmarks with some texts and saves it as a PDF.  It works fine on my local machine because I have Microsoft Word 2013 installed.

However, when this is deployed to the web server it does not work because Microsoft Word 2013 is not installed on it.  As far as I know, Microsoft Word 2013 needs to be installed on the server in order for this to work.  However, some here believe only select components are needed to be copied to the bin folder in order for it to work and Microsoft Word 2013 does not need to be installed.

Does anyone here know what those minimum components would be?  The components I have so far are

Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll,
office.dll

However it process returns the error message 'Cannot create ActiveX component.'  (Since I don't have Visual Studios Installed on the WebServer I don't know which line is causing it).

Or am I correct and we would have to install MS Word 2013 in order for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

In order to automate *any* Office application that application *must* be installed *and licensed* on the machine where the code is executing. No ifs, ands or buts. There is no such thing as "just some components needed".

All that said, running and automating Office applications server-side is *not* supported and can cause problems (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office). For this reason, the Office Open XML file formats were developed, so that Office documents can be generated and manipulated in a server environment.